# How to start a job only after the others are finished (Hangfire)

Tags: c#, jobs, hangfire

I have the following code

```
public string ManterRequisicoesComprasJob(string routingKey, string message)
{
    try
    {
        var request = message.FromJson<HookOutDto>();
        var keys = request.GetKeys();
        var empresa = keys[0];
        var sistema = keys[1].ToInteger();
        var fornecedor = keys[2].ToInteger();
        var negociacao = keys[3];
        var periodo = keys[4].ToInteger();

        return BatchJob.StartNew(batch =>
        {
            var jobId = batch.Enqueue<IHookTargetService>(x => x.Adicionar(null, request.Id, TargetHook.PROCUREMENT));
            jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.GetGrupoRequisicoes(null, empresa, fornecedor, sistema, periodo, negociacao));
            jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.ProcessarRequisicoes(null, empresa, fornecedor, request.Id));
        },
          request.GetJobDescription()
      );
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw exception.Failin();
    }
}
```

In the ProcessarRequisicoes job, I am continuing the code

```
public async Task<RequisicaoCompraRequest> ProcessarRequisicoes(PerformContext context, string empresa, int fornecedor, long parentId)
{
    try
    {
        var result = context.GetAntecedentResult<List<ReqFornecSistemaDto>>();
        var jobId = context.BackgroundJob.Id;
        context.SetJobParameter("PROCESSED", jobId);
        var requisicaoJobs = new List<string>();
        BatchJob.Attach(context.GetBatchId(), batch =>
        {
           foreach (var item in result)
                batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.GetRequisicao(null, empresa, item.Sistema, item.Local, item.Produto)); //duvida

            jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.GetCachedRequisicoes(null));
            jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.GetIdFornecedorProcurement(null, empresa, fornecedor));
            jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IMapperService>(jobId, x => x.MapFromAntecedentResult(null, typeof(Lar.Procurement.Client.RequisicaoCompra.RequestWrapper), null));
            jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.Send(null));
            batch.ContinueJobWith<IHookTargetService>(jobId, x => x.AtualizarFinalizado(null, parentId, TargetHook.PROCUREMENT));
        });

        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw exception.LimTargetException(context, TargetHook.PROCUREMENT);
    }
}
```

I want to process all GetRequisicao jobs and after they are all finished successfully, I want to go to the next job which is GetCachedRequisicoes. If I do it the following way I can even do this, but the problem is that the execution is sequential, one job after the other.

```
foreach (var item in result)
                jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.GetRequisicao(null, empresa, item.Sistema, item.Local, item.Produto));
```

But I would like to run more than one GetRequisicao job at a time and only when they are all completed, go to the next GetCachedRequisicoes job. Can anyone help me?

Comment: are you using  c #8 version minimal (or more) ?

Answer (score -3):

To process multiple `GetRequisicao` jobs concurrently and then proceed to the `GetCachedRequisicoes` job only after all `GetRequisicao` jobs have completed, you can use the concept of batch continuation in Hangfire. Hangfire's Batch feature allows you to group jobs together and define continuations that run after all jobs in the batch have completed.

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

1. **Create a New Batch for `GetRequisicao` Jobs:**

   - Instead of chaining each `GetRequisicao` job to the previous one, create a new batch for these jobs. This allows them to run concurrently.
   - Use `BatchJob.StartNew` to start a new batch inside your existing batch.
2. **Add `GetRequisicao` Jobs to the New Batch:**

   - Add all `GetRequisicao` jobs to this new batch.
3. **Define a Continuation for the New Batch:**

   - After adding all `GetRequisicao` jobs, define a continuation for the new batch that will start the `GetCachedRequisicoes` job. This continuation will only execute once all `GetRequisicao` jobs have completed.

Here's an example based on your code:

```cs
public async Task<RequisicaoCompraRequest> ProcessarRequisicoes(PerformContext context, string empresa, int fornecedor, long parentId)
{
    try
    {
        var result = context.GetAntecedentResult<List<ReqFornecSistemaDto>>();
        var jobId = context.BackgroundJob.Id;
        context.SetJobParameter("PROCESSED", jobId);

        // Start a new batch for GetRequisicao jobs
        var getRequisicaoBatchId = BatchJob.StartNew(batch =>
        {
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                batch.Enqueue<IRequisicaoCompraService>(x => x.GetRequisicao(null, empresa, item.Sistema, item.Local, item.Produto));
            }
        });

        // Define a continuation for the new batch
        BatchJob.ContinueBatchWith(getRequisicaoBatchId, batch =>
        {
            jobId = batch.Enqueue<IRequisicaoCompraService>(x => x.GetCachedRequisicoes(null));
            jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.GetIdFornecedorProcurement(null, empresa, fornecedor));
            jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IMapperService>(jobId, x => x.MapFromAntecedentResult(null, typeof(Lar.Procurement.Client.RequisicaoCompra.RequestWrapper), null));
            jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.Send(null));
            batch.ContinueJobWith<IHookTargetService>(jobId, x => x.AtualizarFinalizado(null, parentId, TargetHook.PROCUREMENT));
        });

        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw exception.LimTargetException(context, TargetHook.PROCUREMENT);
    }
}
```

In this revised approach:

- All `GetRequisicao` jobs are added to a separate batch and run concurrently.
- The `GetCachedRequisicoes` job and subsequent jobs are set as continuations to run only after all `GetRequisicao` jobs have completed.
- This ensures that the `GetCachedRequisicoes` job starts only after the successful completion of all `GetRequisicao` jobs, while still allowing the `GetRequisicao` jobs to run concurrently.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: Thank you Jesse, did not know! Thought it would be great Tool for letting do a summary of topics one already confirmed. I will delete it.